# How to see the metadata of objects in Vertica Database (desc like Oracle)

Tags: ddl, vertica

I would like to know how I can get the metadata of an object in a *Vertica* database; like metadata of a table. Is there any table that stores the metadata of objects (functions, views, tables) in *Vertica* Database.

For example in *Oracle*, I could type the following and get a detailed description of tables or see the code of a procedure.
`oracle :> desc table_name;` 
or

`oracle :> edit proc_name;`

I know that I can see the tables from my schemas with `\dt` command, but is there any way I can see the *DDL* statements that created the objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\d table-name` should get you what you need.

Comment: Ok thx , but this is not the answer !! <br/> or at least this is not what i want . <br/> What i was looking for is the export_objects() function<br/><code> select export_objects('','object_name')<code/> this way you will get the creation script for the object.

Comment: Glad you got to what you needed!

Answer (score 13):

Thanks, but this is not what I want. I was looking for is the `export_objects()` function:

```
select export_objects('','object_name')
```

This way you will get the creation script for the object.

Answer (score 0):

Extra tip: If you specify *only* the schema, you will get all of the objects inside that schema.  Sure beats having to enter a loop where you run export_objects() for every object.